# Memory mapped files in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, memory, file-io

I am not sure if this is possible... Right now I create various .RDP files that my users download directly off the server, with code such as this:

```
        System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath);
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileInfo.Name);
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "Content-Type=application/x-rdp rdp;charset=ISO-8859-1";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());
        Response.WriteFile(fileInfo.FullName);
        Response.End();
```

So a user would click a link and get a file link '~/Download/RemoteServer1234.RDP'.

I don't want these files on my server for various reasons (maintenance and security come to mind). Is there a way to make 'fake files' and give a pointer to the client to just download data that resides in memory? If so, then how does the server ultimately know when to remove any assigned memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use Response.Write() with a StringBuilder (via its ToString() method) containing the RDP file contents (which is an extremely simple [format](http://www.coe.uncc.edu/mosaic/mosaic-anywhere/75.html)).  Of course you can pass an arbitrary string as the filename in the Content-disposition header.

Here's a description of the RDP format (which you apparently already write to a file):
[Remote Desktop File Format](http://www.coe.uncc.edu/mosaic/mosaic-anywhere/75.html)